# How to obtain multi-line norm like representation

Tags: equations, amsmath

I am trying to write a multi-line equation that must be represented by a `norm`. The problem is that when I try to use multi-line equations, I am not able to obtain the `norm` display similar to `\lVert...\rVert`.

I tried to replace the multiline `norm` notations with `\Biggl|\Biggl|...\Biggr|\Biggr` and the result was not so great to see per se.

Here is the `MWE`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}\label{ep_10}
    \begin{split}
    &\lVert x_{n+1}-x_n\rVert =\\
    &\Biggl|\Biggl| \Biggl[\int_{t_0}^{t}left-right-was-fun+\\
    &\int_{t_0}^{t}using-this-biglr-is-not-so-fun\Biggr]\Biggr|\Biggr|.
    \end{split}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: the not-so-good output]

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, that is wrong with `\lVert...\rVert`? `\Biggl\lVert ... \Biggr\rVert` works just fine.

Comment: @daleif I didn't knew about the existence of the latter option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `\!` between your verts.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}\label{ep_10}
    \begin{split}
    &\lVert x_{n+1}-x_n\rVert =\\
    &\Biggl|\!\Biggl| \Biggl[\int_{t_0}^{t}left-right-was-fun+\\
    &\int_{t_0}^{t}using-this-biglr-is-not-so-fun\Biggr]\Biggr|\!\Biggr|.
    \end{split}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As the OP notes, there is a minor spacing difference, which could be alleviated by changing the `\!` to a slightly different negative `\mkern`.

**WITHOUT \mkern CHANGE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}\label{ep_10}
    \begin{split}
    &\lVert x_{n+1}-x_n\rVert =\\
    &\Biggl|\!\Biggl| x_{n+1}-x_n\Biggr|\!\Biggr| = 
    \end{split}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**WITH \mkern CHANGE**

For example, here `\BigglVert` and `\BiggrVert` do exactly that:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\BigglVert{\mkern-.25mu\Biggl|\mkern-2.5mu\Biggl|\mkern-.25mu}
\def\BiggrVert{\mkern-.25mu\Biggr|\mkern-2.5mu\Biggr|\mkern-.25mu}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align}\label{ep_10}
    \begin{split}
    &\lVert x_{n+1}-x_n\rVert =\\
    &\BigglVert x_{n+1}-x_n\BiggrVert = 
    \end{split}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For some reasons the system is not lettting me to accept the answer. I will accept the answer as soon as I am able to. However, the solution works except it changes the spacing properties compared to `\lVert...\rVert`.

Comment: @Raaja See supllements to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools` to define a `\norm` command. The starred version adds an implicit pair of `\left  \right` in front of the delimiters, with the proper spacing. Other than that, it can take as an optional argument one of `\big`, `\Big`, &c., which adds a pair of implicit `\bigl`bigr`, &c.

In addition, a code due to Sébastien Gouezel found in the documentation of the package allows for line breaks in the argument of `\norm`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

    \newcommand\MTkillspecial[1]{% helper macro
    \bgroup
    \catcode`\&=9
    \let\\\relax%
    \scantokens{#1}%
    \egroup
    }
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}\lVert\rVert
\reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper\norm{star}{
\mathopen{#1\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\right.}
#2
\mathclose{\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}#3}}

\begin{document}

 \begin{align}\label{ep_10}
 &\norm[\big]{x_{n+1}-x_n} = \notag\\
  &\begin{aligned}[t] \norm*{ & \int_{t_0}^{t}\text{left-right-was-fun}+{}\\
 & \int_{t_0}^{t}\text{using-this-biglr-is-not-so-fun}. }
 \end{aligned}
 \end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]